# What is the best practice to capitalize words in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm working with languages in R​ails, and I wonder what the best practice is when capitalizing a word.

en.yml:

```
hello: "hello"
```

application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to t(:hello).capitalize, hello_path %> (with capitalization)
<%= link_to t(:hello), hello_path %> (without capitalization)
```

or

en.yml:

```
Hello: "Hello"
hello: "hello"
```

application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to t(:Hello), hello_path %> (with capitalization)
<%= link_to t(:hello), hello_path %> (without capitalization)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that language stuff can get very complex very fast. This is a pretty simple example. Do you have any more realistic use cases?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The second one has a better chance of being correct. When to capitalize and when not to depends on the locale so you can't know if `t(:hello).capitalize` will yield a correct result without looking at the surrounding context. A better approach than either would be to include the context in the symbol, something like this:

```
t(:hello_button)
```

and then in your English YAML:

```
hello_button: "Hello"
```

That way the translations can use whichever case is appropriate for the language in question. Also, sometimes English will use the same word for two things when other languages will use different words: consider *orange* the color and *orange* the fruit; hence the importance of context in your translations.

Furthermore, `capitalize` only works on ASCII characters unless you throw an `mb_chars` into the mix:

```
> 'µ'.capitalize
=> "µ" 
> 'µ'.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
=> "Μ"
```

You might not encounter a leading `µ` but simple accents at the beginning of words are fairly common:

```
> 'éclair'.capitalize
=> "éclair" 
> 'éclair'.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
=> "Éclair"
```

This is just scratching the surface of the difficulties you'll face by assuming that all languages behave like English. Just wait until you have to start dealing with [pluralization rules](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html?id=l10n/pluralforms).

The basic rule in L10N is to treat user-facing strings as opaque blobs of data that you pull out of a database of some sort and show to the user without manipulation in between. Yes, this makes your code more complicated but correctness is sort of important.

---

While I'm here, attempting to translate individual words tends to produce an incomprehensible mess, you'll have better results if you translate entire sentences.

Answer (score 4):

The first. Don't duplicate your data with just capitalization as the difference, it just makes it harder to maintain.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree with you on that, capitalization depends on context.

Comment: Sure, I was also thinking of using the first. But while performance is more expensive to send a language var or use method to capitalize?

Comment: @Gabamnml Running `'hello'.capitalize` 1,000,000 times on my machine takes 820ms. The small performance hit of doing this a few times per page is not worth the maintenance overhead.

Comment: @muistooshort Based on the context the OP gave and their simple example, I assumed the capitalization was grammatical, rather than semantic. In which case the capitalization has nothing to do with the string.

Comment: But the grammatical part depends on the locale, not all languages capitalize words in the same contexts that English does. For example: German capitalizes all proper nouns, English doesn't. There are two pieces of information in play and they both depend on the locale: the word itself and whether or not it should be capitalized; both of these need to be handled by the translation system, you can't handle them separately.

Comment: @muistooshort But if it only varies between languages, then you'd still just have one key, but in different locales. The OP is creating two keys in one locale.

Comment: But the first one is still incorrect: you can't use `capitalize` like that. Whether or not to capitalize at all depends on the language and the context.